# Touchpad stops working after a few minutes on Ubuntu 22.10

Tags: drivers, touchpad, 22.10

I'm fairly inexperienced with Linux in general and I recently installed Ubuntu 22.10 on my Acer Aspire (model number is E5-774G-52W1). I am having an issue where the touchpad will work for a few minutes and then it will suddenly stop working. When it is in the state that it does not work, it will just do an action of left clicking several times when I try to move the pointer around.

When I run the command `xinput -list` I see the following:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]  
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]  
⎜   ↳ ELAN0501:00 04F3:3019 Mouse               id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]  
⎜   ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                  id=17   [slave  pointer  (2)]  
⎜   ↳ Holtek USB Gaming Mouse                   id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]  
⎜   ↳ ELAN0501:00 04F3:3019 Touchpad            id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]  
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]  
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ HD WebCam: HD WebCam                      id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Acer WMI hotkeys                          id=18   [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Holtek USB Gaming Mouse                   id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Holtek USB Gaming Mouse                   id=19   [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I have a mouse plugged in as well, so pay no mind to the gaming mouse entries. I only plugged this in as a response to the issues I'm having.

Additionally, I have run `xinput --list-props 15` and `xinput --list-props 17` both twice. Once when the touchpad was working and once when the touchpad stopped working about an hour latter. I compared each property before and after and there was no difference.

I suspect I might have an issue with the driver, but I am needing some help verifying exactly what the issue might be. I have verified that the touchpad is enabled in the settings. I have verified that the mousepad lock is not enabled. I have rebooted several times and each time, it will work at first, then will stop working as previously described.

Please let me know if any of you have any ideas, or if you would like me to post any more information. I was able to find a helpful debugging touchpad post on an Ubuntu wiki, but I couldn't find a fix there that worked for me.

UPDATE

I found a recommendation to try running `sudo rmmod psmouse` and `sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps`. When I run the second line I get the following error message.

```
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:712 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/psmouse.conf line 1: ignoring bad line starting with 'elantech_smbus=0'
```

If anybody has any ideas fix this or further troubleshoot, please let me know. If I find any solution, I will post it here as well.

Comment: Sounds like the mouse and the track pad conflict. Have you tried without the mouse?

Comment: Yes. I only plug in the mouse because there is a problem. I have tried booting without the mouse plugged in several times and the problem is still there.

Comment: Would be a good idea to edit the question and add this important detail.